# real analogue of Weil conjectures?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a theorem (or theorems) that can be thought of a real analogue of Weil conjectures? One can replace the finite field by real numbers and Frobenius by complex conjugation; counting points can perhaps be replaced by Euler characteristic or a more refined invariant of the set of real points. Of course, Lefschetz fixed point formula can be applied here, but is there something more specific one can say?

Comment: You might have a look at *Analogues kählériens de certaines conjectures de Weil* by J.-P. Serre, Ann. of Math. 71 (1960), 392-394.

Comment: Thanks for the reference; however, it looks like this is a complex analogue of Weil conjectures, not the real one: Serre doesn't talk about real points as far as I see.